# map a binary function over pairs of lists in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why do I get in Python2

```
>>> map(max,[1,2],[3,1])
[3, 2]
```

and in Python3

```
>>> map(max,[1,2],[3,1])
<map object at 0x10c2235f8>
```

?

What should replace `map(max,[1,2],[3,1])` in Python3 ?

I read that one should use list comprehension in Python3 but

```
>>> [max(i,j) for i in [1,2] for j in [3,1]]
[3, 1, 3, 2]
```

does not give the desired result and neither do the variations that came to mind.

Comment: @Dark technically, not a generator, just an iterator.

Comment: list-comp: `[max(i, j) for i, j in zip([1,2], [3,1])]`.

Comment: @ekhumoro: thanks this is elegant. Do python programmers have an opinion on which of the two solutions (using list or using zip and comprehension) is more appropriate?

Comment: @AlexanderKurz. There are probably SO questions that discuss the relative performance. Otherwise, it's really just a matter of personal taste, or house style (or even just "what looks right" in the current code context).

Answer (score 2):

That's because `Python2` returns a `List` for multiple return values.

From [Pydoc[2]](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

> If there are multiple arguments, map() returns a list consisting of
>   tuples containing the corresponding items from all iterables (a kind
>   of transpose operation). The iterable arguments may be a sequence or
>   any iterable object; the result is always a list.

Whereas `Python3` returns an `Iterable`.

From [Pydoc[3]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

> Return an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable,
>   yielding the results.

---

So to get the `list` in `Python3`, just do :

```
list(map(...))
```

Basically :

```
>>> list(map(max,[1,2],[3,1]))
=> [3, 2]
```

Comment: thanks ... do python programmers have an opinion on which of the two solutions (using list or using zip and comprehension) is preferable?

Comment: The above solution is the preffered way since you can use the iterable itself using `.next` instead of going for lists and also has shorter code and is easier to read.